Relacionar una lista y una lista de listas
Tengo una duda con respecto a un código que estoy haciendo y es que quiero relacionar una lista y una lista de listas para que si existe una coincidencia con sus valores me guarde en una variable el otro dato que acompaña a la lista de listas.
Ejemplo:
nuevos_primos_esenciales_final=[1, '001'], [[4, 6], '1-0'], [[6, 7], '11-']]

implicantes_esenciales=[1, [4, 6], [6, 7]]

Si relaciona [4, 6], que me retorne el valor '101' y me lo guarde en una lista nueva.

¿De dónde sale el valor 101?

la variable nuevos_primos_esenciales_final es una tupla de dos elementos, no una lista.

El código que muestras no es válido. Los "[]" están mal anidados.

Buenas.
Aporta el código que hayas intentado ya para poder ayudarte mejor.

Básicamente lo puedes hacer con un bucle FOR y el condicional IF, también te coloqué bien los [], ya que lo tenías mal planteados.
Aquí el código:
nuevos_primos_esenciales_final = [[1, '001'], [[4, 6], '1-0'], [[6, 7], '11-']]
implicantes_esenciales = [1, [4, 6], [6, 7]]

valores_encontrados = []

for implicante in implicantes_esenciales:
    if isinstance(implicante, list):
        for item in nuevos_primos_esenciales_final:
            if implicante == item[0]:
                valores_encontrados.append(item[1])
                break
    else:
        for item in nuevos_primos_esenciales_final:
            if implicante == item[0]:
                valores_encontrados.append(item[1])
                break

print("Valores encontrados:", valores_encontrados)


Una versión más corta.
Agregue un par de valores en implicantes_esenciales para ver que pasa cuando no existe el correspondiente par en la otra lista.
nuevos_primos_esenciales_final = [[1, '001'], [[4, 6], '1-0'], [[6, 7], '11-']]
implicantes_esenciales=[1, [4, 6], [6, 7], 8, 9]

salida = []
for imp in implicantes_esenciales:
    for item in nuevos_primos_esenciales_final:
        if imp == item[0]:
            salida.append(item[1])
print(salida)

produce:
['001', '1-0', '11-']

Process finished with exit code 0


Una solución más simple:
print([p for i, p in primos if i in implicantes])


El código da error: ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2) ¿Lo probaste primero? ¿Que aberración escribistes? ¿Qué esperas resulte de for i, p i primos, siendo primos una lista?

@CandidMoe cometiste un error al transcribir el código, en cualquier caso agradezco tu advertencia sobre un posible error
